# Please can anyone explain me this warning while writing a c program(use of extern keyword)

Tags: c

file name :- next.c

```
extern int global_var = 2;
```

file name :- try.c

```
#include <stdion.h>
#include "next.c"
void main()
{
printf("%d", global_var);
}
```

The waring that I am getting

```
In file include form try.c:2:0:
next.c.1.12: warning: 'globl_var' initialized and declared 'extern'
 extern in global_var = 22;
           ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: The message means what it says.  It is at best aconventional to use `extern type name = value;` — use either `extern type name;` or `type name = value;` but not both.  You should either declare (but not initialize) the variable, or you should define and initialize the variable but not attempt to declare it too.  In a header, you should not include the initializer.  You should not normally include a `.c` file inside another file (though there are exceptions to that guideline, but the code shown doesn't qualify as an exception).

Comment: `#include "next.c"` well... it's not illegal but it's very unusual to include a c-file....

Comment: ok got it. It means this warning is rising because of the file type

Comment: @Vivek-Raj No, it's not because of the file type.

Comment: @Vivek - The compiler doesn't care much about the file type.It is just a convention that a file intended to be included is named .h, while a file intended to be compiled separately is named with a .c extension. We humans see that in `#include "next.c"` something is a bit surprising. either in the name or in the usage.

Answer (score 3):

The warning itself tells you that your code is wrong. The messages can be "translated" into something like: "Declaring a variable as extern **and** at the same time assigning a value, is wrong.

It seems you have misunderstood the normal way to use include files. You don't do:

```
#include "next.c"
```

What you do is

```
#include "next.h"
```

That is... a c-file contains source code for a unit. The corresponding h-file contains information about the unit that you want to share with other units (aka c-files).

Try this:

next.h:

```
extern int global_var;  // Tell other c-files that include next.h
                        // that a int-variable with name global_var
                        // exists
```

next.c:

```
int global_var = 2;     // Define and initialize global_var
```

and in try.c do:

```
#include "next.h"       // Include next.h to know what the unit next.c
                        // makes available for use in try.c
```

The above is for a global variable defined by the unit next.c. For functions is pretty much the same.

Assume that next.c implements a function `foo` that you want try.c to call... Then you do the same, i.e. you write the functions source code in next.c and use next.h to tell other units that the function is available. Like:

next.h:

```
extern int global_var;  // Tell other c-files that include next.h
                        // that a int-variable with name global_var
                        // exists

void foo(int a, int b);  // Tell other c-files that include next.h
                         // that a function with name foo
                         // exists
```

next.c:

```
int global_var = 2;     // Define and initialize global_var

void foo(int a, int b)   // Define foo
{
    ... source code ...
}
```

and in try.c use it like:

```
#include "next.h"       // Include next.h to know what the unit next.c
                        // makes available for use in try.c

#include "next.h"       // Include next.h to know what the unit next.c
                        // makes available for use in try.c

int bar()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 42;
    foo(x, y);    // Call function foo in unit next.c
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**extern** is used to tell compiler that variable is declared out of scope.

*first.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "second.h"

int main(){

    extern const float pi;

    printf("pi : %f\n" , pi);

    return 0;
}
```

*second.h*

```
const float pi = 3.148;
```

*output*

> pi : 3.148000

***why to use extern?***

> to prevent local redeclaration of variable and make code more readable and understandable

*example error*
*first.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "second.h"

int main(){

    extern const float pi;
    const float pi;

    printf("pi : %f\n" , pi);

    return 0;
}
```

***output***

> first.c: In function 'main':
> first.c:7:17: error: redeclaration of 'pi' with no linkage
> 7 |     const float pi;
> |                 ^~
> In file included from first.c:2:
> second.h:1:13: note: previous definition of 'p 
> ' with type 'float'
> 1 | const float pi = 3.148;
> |             ^~

Answer (score 0):

extern tells the compiler that the extern declared symbol is **defined** in a different source file or rather translation unit .

When you assign a value to an extern symbol, you basically say  " the definition is somewhere else, but the definition is [x]"

To fix that, you should "define" the variable somewhere without "extern".